# JSON => GoogleCharts formatting

Tags: json, charts, datatable, visualization

I am desperately trying to get my GoogleChart working. This code always throws an error though:

```
        function drawChart() 
        { 
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(); 
          data.addColumn('number', 'hour'); 
          data.addColumn('number', 'TriggerCount'); 
          var JsonManuallyEncoded = '{1:{1:01,2:4},2:{1:03,2:4},3:{1:04,2:48},4:{1:05,2:59},5:{1:06,2:59},6:{1:07,2:87},7:{1:08,2:62},8:{1:09,2:46},9:{1:10,2:61},10:{1:11,2:71},11:{1:12,2:54},12:{1:13,2:61},13:{1:14,2:89},14:{1:15,2:58},15:{1:16,2:122},16:{1:17,2:108},17:{1:18,2:64},18:{1:19,2:50},19:{1:20,2:10},20:{1:21,2:18}};'
          data.addRows(JsonManuallyEncoded);


        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')); 
        chart.draw(data);}
```

The Firefox console says: "Argument given to addRows must be eiter a number or an array".
I suspect that the format of the JSON string is not correct, but I cannot figure out what's wrong. Can somebody please identify my mistake? It's probably trivial but I am spending hours on this already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the documentation for [addRows](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_addRows)? but you should not pass the row data to `addRows` as a JSON encoded string, you should pass a array of arrays data structure. I think there may be other API functions for passing a JSON string so i recommend you to read the documentation and look at the examples.

Comment: Thank you Mattias! But are you entirely sure that JSON is a no-go for addRow? I was convinced that addRows can accept a JSON string. In fact, somebody had sent me an example which used JSON for addRow - but I cannot test wheter his example is functional since he didn't send me the source.

Comment: Not sure but i don't think so. The documentation for `addRow` is just above `addRows` so take a look there. None of the examples uses a string as argument but i can't really see what the problem is, can't you just not put quotes around the JSON?