# postgreSQL to googlecharts

Tags: php, postgresql, google-visualization

I use PHP to pull data from postgreSQL, which I will be using to construct GoogleChart dataTables. GoogleCharts accepts arrays of arrays (format: [[data1, data2, data3],[data4, data5, data6]].

In order to format the array properly, I use the following syntax:

```
$GoogleChartString ="["; //opening bracket inserted
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($QueryResult)) 
{
$GoogleChartString = $GoogleChartString . "[" .implode(",", $row) . "],"; 
}
$GoogleChartString = substr($GoogleChartString,0,-1)."]";
```

Now, some fields are strings and some are numbers. GoogleCharts DataTables expect strings to be single-quoted. However, pg_fetch_row does not put any delimiters around the strings. How can I, in an elegant and efficient way, generate the appropriate formats that is expected by GoogleCharts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good news and one bad news.

The bad news: You did wrote too much code so far, you literally wasted characters and probably your own code stands in your way so you have prevented yourself from solving this question.

The good news: Build an array in PHP, then use the [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) function and you don't need to care about the formatting. It's [Json](http://json.org/).

```
$googleChart = array();
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($QueryResult)) {
    $googleChart[] = $row;
}
$googleChartString = json_encode($googleChart);
```

Whenever you deal with some API, look for the specification (e.g. Json). Then take a look in the PHP manual how that specification is supported. Often out-of-the-box, otherwise there are a lot of libraries you can use as well.

***Edit:***

- Some technical reference (yes, Json): https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews

Code Fragment ([Demo](http://codepad.org/fuTNk4s2)):

```
$data = array(array(data1, data2, data3),array(data4, data5, data6));

echo json_encode($data);
```

Output:

```
[["data1","data2","data3"],["data4","data5","data6"]]
```

Comment: Thank you Hakre for taking the time to address my question. I would be _delighted_ to pass the array to GoogleCharts as a JSON string!However, as far as I understand, GoogleChart does not support Json inputs. See this answer to a previous post: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10870108/1320581) - that's why I wrote all the code! Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Well, please share on what specifically and technically you base your understanding. I would be *delighted* if you add that.

Comment: Thank you Hakre, and sorry if you perceived me as impertinent - I did not mean to come across as such. My technical understanding (which is limited, as I am a molecular biologist and I am only superficially dabbing into databases) is based on the answer posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869870/json-googlecharts-formatting/10870108#10870108

Comment: oops, I hadn't seen your edit. Now that makes a lot more sense to me! Many thanks.

Comment: @aag: It does not mean that I'm right. In case this still does not work, add the code-fragment where it is visible how you pass the data to google charts so it's clear what happens next. But I really assume this is json, because that is very common. And good luck with biology, create some cool new species.